# Simplify my class mapping common class properties between model and viewmodel classes

Tags: c#, linq

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 app and I map properties between model and viewmodel and vice versa.

I could use automapper to do this but since I don't need mapping rules to convince me to use it as I mostly do simple 1 to 1 mapping the  performance overhead that automapper will add is not worthwhile.If I have mapping differences I'll map it manually where I reference it in my controller.

Here is my code

```
public class Dog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }

    public int? CreatedBy{ get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateCreated { get; set; }
}

public class DogViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }


    public static implicit operator DogViewModel(Dog dm)
    {
        var vm= new DogViewModel{
            Id = dm.Id,
            Name = dm.Name,
            BirthDate = dm.BirthDate 
       };
        return vm;
    }

    public static implicit operator Dog(DogViewModel vm)
    {
        var dm = new Dog
        {
            Id = vm.Id,
            Name = vm.Name,
            BirthDate = vm.BirthDate 
        };
        return dm;
    }
}
```

This allows me to in my controller actionmethods easily map one class to another.

e.g.

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
    {
        var dog= await _db.Dogs.FirstOrDefaultAsync(d => md.Id == id);
        DogViewModel dogVm = dog;
        ...

     }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(DogViewModel dogVm)
    {
       Dog dog= dogVm;
       ...
    }
```

In my index ActionMethod I need to map a list of items.

```
  public async  Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var dogs = await _db.Dogs.ToListAsync();

        var dogVms = new List<DogViewModel>();
        foreach (var dog in dogs)
        {
            DogViewModel dogVm = dog;
            dogVms.Add(dogVm);
        }
        return View(dogVms);
    }
```

Question: Is there a way in LINQ or some other way in C# to eliminate the above foreach clause to simplify this code?

Comment: You crate a `List<MonthViewModel>()` but you are adding `DogViewModel`s - is this correct? Is `DogViewModel` derived from `MonthViewModel`? I cannot try it out because you didn' show the `MonthViewModel` but I think since you have an implicit cast operator this might work `_db.Months.ToListAsync().Cast<DogViewModel>().ToList();` that repaces your loop.

Comment: Sorry was just a typo. I corrected it. Should read dog not month

Comment: I think your understanding of how ViewModel and Model work is not that good yet. Assigning a Model to morph into a VM is not a good practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Providing

```
var dogVms = new List<MonthViewModel>();
```

is meant to actually be

```
var dogVms = new List<DogViewModel>();
```

Then to use LINQ you could do

```
List<DogViewModel> dogVms = (from dog in dogs select (DogViewModel)dog).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also write;

```
var dogVms = dogs.Select<Dog, DogViewModel>(dog => dog);
```

(assuming you have implicit operators)

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Code Review. Please explain more on why your way is better.

Comment: To add on to Coffee's comment: Here, we expect answers that both provide a better way and explain why those ways are better.

Comment: hi guys. because it's shorter and seems more elegant :)